# get detail value from database on <tr> hover

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hello guys i have a problem which i can't figure out for a little while. i have a loop which return value from database and i want each value to view their value on onmouseover property of JavaScript. but it only shows the first row value for all the  tags. here is the php part of code

```
$result = "<table id='displayDiv' width='1000' class='table_info table-bordered table-striped table-hover'>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan='6' class='plate'>Follow-Up Events</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style='text-align:center; color:#FFF; background: #31B0D5;'>
                            <td>Customer</td>
                            <td>Plate</td>
                            <td class='col-md-4'>Problem</td>
                            <td>Date Created</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>";

foreach ($followArray as $customer) {

$result = $result .
        "<tr style='text-align:center; background: #FFF; color:#105a99; font-weight:bold;'>
                    <td>$customer->company</td>
                    <td id='plate' onmouseover='plate();' onmouseout='plateout();'>$customer->plate</td>
                    <td>$customer->problem</td>
                    <td>$customer->date</td>
                </tr>";
}
$result = $result . "</table><div id'white'></div>";
```

and the javascript

```
function plate() {
document.getElementById("white").innerHTML = $("#plate").text();
}
function plateout() {
 document.getElementById("white").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: All your elements have the id `plate`. That needs to be unique.

Comment: Try to use `this.document.getElementById("white").innerHTML`

Comment: how can i fix the ids. if i have to use dynamic id for each div then i have to use each id on document.getElementById and that would be very tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using native js, just pass `this` into your plate function and use `this.innerHTML`.

Also fix the html - ids should be unique so either change it to a class or append a unique number onto the end (in the example below I have changed it to a class) - you should never have an id in a loop (unless you are appending an index or something like that).

And there should be an `=` in the white div

```js
function plate(columnCell) {
  document.getElementById('white').innerHTML = columnCell.innerHTML;
}
function plateout() {
  document.getElementById('white').innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<table id='displayDiv' width='1000' class='table_info table-bordered table-striped table-hover'>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='6' class='plate'>Follow-Up Events</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='text-align:center; color:#FFF; background: #31B0D5;'>
    <td>Customer</td>
    <td>Plate</td>
    <td class='col-md-4'>Problem</td>
    <td>Date Created</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='text-align:center; background: #FFF; color:#105a99; font-weight:bold;'>
    <td>$customer->company</td>
    <td class='plate' onmouseover='plate(this);' onmouseout='plateout(this);'>$customer->plate</td>
    <td>$customer->problem</td>
    <td>$customer->date</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='text-align:center; background: #FFF; color:#105a99; font-weight:bold;'>
    <td>$customer->company</td>
    <td class='plate' onmouseover='plate(this);' onmouseout='plateout();'>$customer->plate1</td>
    <td>$customer->problem</td>
    <td>$customer->date</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='text-align:center; background: #FFF; color:#105a99; font-weight:bold;'>
    <td>$customer->company</td>
    <td class='plate' onmouseover='plate(this);' onmouseout='plateout(this);'>$customer->plate2</td>
    <td>$customer->problem</td>
    <td>$customer->date</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="white"></div>
```

If you want a jQuery solution then using the new class of plate (and removing the onmouseover and onmouseout from the html) you can do something like this:

```js
// run in your document ready

var white = $('#white');

$('.plate').hover(
  function() {
    // mouseover
    white.text($(this).text());
  }, function() {
    // mouseoout
    white.text('');
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much brother. you saved my day.

Comment: No probs, glad I could help :)